# Angular 6: How to implement route guard with auth service

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

How to use data from auth.service.ts in route guard. From auth.service.ts I use verify token api to check the validity (test in postman return {"valid" : true}). But I do not understand how to implement with route guard.

Code for auth.service.ts to verify token. If token valid return true

```
 verifyToken(id:string, token: string) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('a', id).set('b', token);

    this.base_url = environment.MYAPI_REST_API_URL;

    this.customersObservable = this.httpClient.get(this.base_url +'/registration/application/verifyConfirmationToken', {params});

     this.data = JSON.stringify(this.customersObservable);

     return this.data;
}
```

Code for route Guard

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['a'];
        this.token = params['b'];
    });

    if (this.auth.verifyToken(this.id,this.token)) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    // window.location.href='http://www.cnn.com/';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In the verify token method, you should validate the token, but that's what you are not doing in that method, you can use `angular-jwt` library to check whether token is valid or not https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Comment: Why are you making api call in the verify token method? Just to validate token?

Comment: .subscribe is async, you don't get the data immediately, so in verifyToken arg will unset

Comment: Not clear about the implementation you have done. Simply return a `boolean` from the `verifyToken` method and let that know in the canActivate method. canActive method just want to return true or false. Don't add so much responsibility in the canActivate method

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by creating Auth Guard service.

```js
// Auth Gaurd Service
// In AuthGaurdService

@Injectable()
class CanTokenActive implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private currentUser: UserToken) {}
 
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    // Logic to check token is exist or not.
  }
}


// In routhing module

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: Home,
        canActivate: ['canTokenActive']
      }
    ])
  ]
 })
class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
1) 
ng generate guard auth   [ Create guard, the file name would be like 
auth.guard.ts ]

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from 
'@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
    private myRoute: Router){
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | 
   boolean {
    if(this.auth.isLoggednIn()){
      return true;
    }else{
      this.myRoute.navigate(["login"]);
      return false;
    }
  }
}


2)  ng g c login  [Create login page ]
ng g c nav  [Create nav page ]
ng g c home  [Create home page ]
ng g c registration  [Create registration page ]


3) App.module.ts file add below contents

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule,Router,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from 
'./registration/registration.component';

// canActivate added for AuthGuard.
// Add in Providers: [AuthService,AuthGuard],

const myRoots: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' , canActivate: 
  [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      myRoots,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [AuthService,AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


4) Add link in nav.component.html

  <p color="primary">
  <button  routerLink="/home">Home</button>
  <button  *ngIf="!auth.isLoggednIn()" 
  routerLink="/register">Register</button>
  <button  *ngIf="!auth.isLoggednIn()" routerLink="/login">Login</button>
  <button  *ngIf="auth.isLoggednIn()" 
  (click)="auth.logout()">Logout</button>
  </p>


4.1)  Add in nav.component.ts file

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}


5) 
ng g service auth  [Create service page Add below code in authservice.ts]

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private myRoute: Router) { }
  sendToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("LoggedInUser", token)
  }
  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("LoggedInUser")
  }
  isLoggednIn() {
    return this.getToken() !== null;
  }
  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem("LoggedInUser");
    this.myRoute.navigate(["Login"]);
  }
}


6) add content in login.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private myRoute: Router,
    private auth: AuthService) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  login() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.auth.sendToken(this.form.value.email)
      this.myRoute.navigate(["home"]);
    }
  }
}


6.1)  add in logincomponent.html page

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="login()">
<div>
<input  type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" />
</div>
<div>
<input  type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" 
/>
</div>
<button type="submit" color="primary">Login</button>
</form>


7) Add below code in app.component.html

<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```